# How to execute an Sparql query in android using androjena 0.5

Tags: android, sparql, jena

I'm trying to execute a simple Sparql query from my android device. The online endpoint that I am using is https://dbpedia.org/sparql with URI http://dbpedia.org and the query:

> "select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100".

I successfully imported to my Android project the libraries of androjena 0.5 and arqoid 0.5. Studing the code from [this](http://technologymashup.blogspot.com/2013/10/sparql-in-android.html) helpful tutorial I changed some lines and I ended up with the following code:

```js
import java.util.List;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Syntax;

public class SparqlExamples {
    public String queryRemoteSparqlEndpoint() {

        String queryString = "select distinct ?Concept where {[] a ?Concept} LIMIT 100";
        String sparqlEndpointUri = "https://dbpedia.org";
        Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString, Syntax.syntaxARQ);
        query.setLimit(10);
        query.setOffset(1);
        QueryExecution qe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEndpointUri, query);
        ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();
        StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
        List<String> columnNames = resultSet.getResultVars();
        while (resultSet.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution solution = resultSet.next();
            for (String var : columnNames) {
                results.append(var + ": ");
                if (solution.get(var) == null) {
                    results.append("{null}");
                } else if (solution.get(var).isLiteral()) {
                    results.append(solution.getLiteral(var).toString());
                } else {
                    results.append(solution.getResource(var).getURI());
                }
                results.append('\n');
            }
            results.append("-----------------\n");
        }
        qe.close();
        return results.toString();
    }
}
```

and the MainActivity:

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        String results = new SparqlExamples().queryRemoteSparqlEndpoint();
        Log.d("results","results"+String.valueOf(results));
    }
}
```

I will appreciate any idea that could help in this issue.

Comment: What's the specific problem

Comment: Next time, provide the error message you receive...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The specific problem is that I do not receive any response from server and the app crashes after installation. LogCat shows that the problem begins in this command:  ResultSet resultSet = qe.execSelect();

Comment: Please edit your question to include the "specific problem" details. Note that the `sparqlEndpointUri` for DBpedia is `https://dbpedia.org/sparql` (not `https://dbpedia.org`), and this *must* be reflected in your code.

Comment: If there's a crash, there's usually a crash stacktrace you should include here. If I'd have to guess, it's `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. You need to offload network calls to a background thread.

Comment: You may also benefit from [this Virtuoso-focused Jena doc](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider) (as Virtuoso is the engine behind the DBpedia endpoint).

Answer (score 0):

This --

```
    String sparqlEndpointUri = "https://dbpedia.org";
```

-- should be this --

```
    String sparqlEndpointUri = "https://dbpedia.org/sparql";
```

Comment: I tried this but still is not working. However, thanks for the interest.

Comment: @ADamian "not working" is not helpful... **what** does not work? errors, empty result, etc?